# Laravel pluck with relations fails

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried the following

```
     $trucks = TttatTblTrucks::with('trucktype')
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$from, $to])
        ->pluck('trucktype.description')
    ;
```

and getting an error  Unknown column 'trucktype.description'

In my `TttatTblTrucks`

```
public function trucktype(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\TblTruckTypes','id','truck_category');
}
```

In my table i have

```
tbl_trucks //model is TttatTblTrucks

id, truck_category ....
```

In my table

```
truck_category //model is TblTruckTypes
 id, description, ...
```

Where am i going wrong during pluck as the sam query with get instead of pluck returns

```
        {
        "id": 2207,
        "truck_category": 28,
        "trucktype": {
            "id": 28,
            "description": "mmnuakrt",
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't exactly know why, but I can't "refine" using Eloquent Query function `pluck`, but using Collection function `lists`:

```
$trucks = TttatTblTrucks::with('trucktype')->whereBetween('created_at',[$from, $to])->get()->lists('trucktype.description');
```

I guess it must be related with the fact that `with` is modifying the result and you longer can refine on a model, but on the returned collection.

By the way: `lists` is not deprecated on Collections. It's only that the function `lists` has been renamed to `pluck` on `Eloquent Queries`, but it remains as `lists` on `Collections` (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/lists-deprecated-replacement).